# React Native Upload on firebase Storage even in background

Tags: firebase, react-native, background, upload, react-native-firebase

I'm actually working on a react native application, and I need to upload picture/video even if user close the app during the upload, for the moment when someone put the app in background, the upload is paused/stopped

So I need to fix it with firebase, I use Rnfirebase.
Thx for your help